# Code generation using Ant

Tags: ant, code-generation

I would like to generate a file from an intermixed content of inline code snippets and contents of other files. Something like:

```
<target name="generate-js-function">
    <concat destfile="mycode.js">
        <header trimleading="yes">
            // begin auto generated
            var create = function() {
                function createHtmlSnippet1() {
        </header>

        <fileset file="snippet1.js"/>

        <header>
                }
        </header>

        <header trimleading="yes">
            // begin auto generated
            var create = function() {
                function createHtmlSnippet2() {
        </header>

        <fileset file="snippet2.js"/>

        <header>
                }
        </header>

                return '' + createHtmlSnippet1() + createHtmlSnippet2();

            }
            // end auto generated
        </header>
    </concat>
</target>
```

AFAIK, there can be only one `header` / `footer`, so what's the proper way to do it?

*Update*: if anything in the question isn't clear - please ask - I'll clarify happily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inline snippets you can use the [`string` resource](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#string):

```
<concat destfile="mycode.js">
  <string>
    // begin auto generated
    var create = function() {
            function createHtmlSnippet1() {
  </string>

  <fileset file="snippet1.js"/>

  <string>
    }
  </string>

  ...

</concat>
```

The only downside is that it doesn't support the `trimleading` attribute, but it will allow you to have the code inline in your build file.

Comment: Can I still apply regex filters?

Comment: Yes, you can add a `filterchain` to filter the whole thing, or you can filter individual files by using nested `concat`s which have their own `filterchain`s.

Answer (score 1):

Write each inline JS portion into its own file, and concat all the files.

You can use the [echo](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) task to write to temp files dynamically from the ant build file, and then concat the snippet files and the temp files.